# Include href in both glyphicon and anchor tag

Tags: html, anchor

I have a fairly simple question I think, but I can not seem to find the solution. I have a glyphicon and text that I would like to give am `href` to. I am able to place the href tag to the anchor tag, obviously, but can not apply it to the glyphicon...  I will post line of code below.

```
<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-credit-card"></i><a href="http://www.google.com">Test Text</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### If you want a different link

In HTML, `i` tags cannot have the `href` attribute. So you need to wrap it in an achor:

```
<a href="some link"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-credit-card"></i></a>
```

Or if it is applicable, you can use JavaScript instead:

```
<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-credit-card" onclick="myFunction()"></i>
```

---

#### If you want the same link

This makes the glyphicon part of the same anchor:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-credit-card"></i> Test Text</a>
```